# ggplot on point estimates and confidence intervals

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot the data frame using ggplot that looks like  the plot at the bottom of http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/logit.htm.

```
       a<-data.frame(Year=c("2012","2012","2012","2013","2013","2013","2014","2014","2014"),
          Engagement=rep(c("low","med","high"),3),
         cost=c(4464.88,4690.14,4342.72,5326.63,5000.03,3967.02,4646.27,4282.38,3607.79),
         lower=c(4151.4,5027.51,4095.73,4366.82,4682.85,3715.86,3775.25,3642.41,3235.43),
         upper=c(4778.35,5625.75,5196.81,5013.45,5317.2,4848.89,4910.19,4291.64,3980.14))
```

I tried:

```
k<-ggplot(a,aes(x=Year,y=cost))
k+geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=lower,ymax=upper,fill=Engagement),alpha=0.2)+
geom_pointrange(aes(x=Year,y=cost,ymin=lower,ymax=lower),size=1,width=0.2,color="blue")
```

I appreciate all the helps.

I just also tried :

```
pd <- position_dodge(0.1)
k<-ggplot(a,aes(x=Year,y=cost))
k+geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=lower,ymax=upper,fill=Engagement),alpha=0.2)+
  geom_line(position=pd,aes(color=Engagement))
```

error message:

```
ymax not defined: adjusting position using y instead
geom_path: Each group consist of only one observation. 
Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
```

Answer (score 5):

Thanks everybody, problem solved:

```
k+geom_line(aes(group=Engagement,color=Engagement))+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=lower,ymax=upper,color=Engagement,width=0.2))
```

[image]

Comment: Answering your own question is often encouraged as a way to help future users. But to be a helpful good answer you need to explain *something* about what the problem was and why this works. And if it was actually Harrison's code that solved the problem, then you should just "accept" that answer (by clicking the checkbox next to it) and not bother with your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming by "look like" you mean add the ribbons to your graph. If so then the issue is stemming from the `Year` variable in the `a` data.frame. It currently has factor class and it needs to be numeric.

If you add this before you call your ggplot graph you should see the ribbons:

```
a$Year <- as.numeric(a$Year)
```

You could also modify your entire assignment of `a` to the following:

```
a<-data.frame(Year=as.numeric(c("2012","2012","2012","2013","2013","2013","2014","2014","2014")),
              Engagement=rep(c("low","med","high"),3),
              cost=c(4464.88,4690.14,4342.72,5326.63,5000.03,3967.02,4646.27,4282.38,3607.79),
              lower=c(4151.4,5027.51,4095.73,4366.82,4682.85,3715.86,3775.25,3642.41,3235.43),
              upper=c(4778.35,5625.75,5196.81,5013.45,5317.2,4848.89,4910.19,4291.64,3980.14))
```